# I recently wrote this code below in kotlin to make it a yes or no question but when the user respond with yes or no it will not go to the next

Tags: kotlin

```
fun basicResponses(_message: String): String {

      
        val message =_message.toLowerCase()
        
        return when {

            message.contains("Yes")||message.contains("yes") || message.contains("YES") || message.contains("No")||message.contains("no")||message.contains("NO") -> {

                "Question 1:Do you Have ...?"

            }

            message.contains("Yes")||message.contains("yes") || message.contains("No")||message.contains("no")||message.contains("NO")-> {
                "Question 2:Do you Have ... ?"
            }

            message.contains("Yes")||message.contains("yes") || message.contains("No")||message.contains("no")||message.contains("NO")-> {
                "Question 3:Do you feel ... ?"
            }

            message.contains("Yes")||message.contains("yes") || message.contains("No")||message.contains("no")||message.contains("NO") -> {
                "Question 4:Do you Have ... ?"
            }

            message.contains("Yes")||message.contains("yes") || message.contains("No")||message.contains("no")||message.contains("NO") -> {
                "Question 5:Do you Have ... ?"
            }

            message.contains("Yes")||message.contains("yes") || message.contains("No")||message.contains("no")||message.contains("NO") -> {
                "Question 6:Do you Have ... ?"
            }

            message.contains("Yes")||message.contains("yes") || message.contains("No")||message.contains("no")||message.contains("NO") -> {
                "Question 7:Do you Have... ?"
            }

            message.contains("Yes")||message.contains("yes") || message.contains("No")||message.contains("no")||message.contains("NO") -> {
                "Question 8:Do you feel ... ?"
            }

            message.contains("Yes")||message.contains("yes") || message.contains("No")||message.contains("no")||message.contains("NO") -> {
                "Question 9:Do you Have Redness or flaky skin...?"
            }

            message.contains("Yes")||message.contains("yes") || message.contains("No")||message.contains("no")||message.contains("NO")-> {
                "Question 10:Do you feel Pain in any area of... ?"
            }

            //When the program doesn't understand...
            else -> {
                "sorry! your answer can be only yes or no"
                }
            }
        }
```

the above code uses yes or no questions which the user answers either yes or no only the problem i have is the code doesn't go to the next question after only asking the first weather the answer is yes or no so how can i make it go to the second and up to the tenth and collect the result ?

Comment: Can you add some more context to this?  How are you collecting the user's response?  It would be helpful to see where you are calling this function

Comment: seems you have returning a question based on answer? shouldn't that be the other way around? also, looks like you want to ask all questions irrespective of the response for earlier. in that case you don't need `when`. you need to loop until user inputs valid text.

Comment: I wanted the questions to be static means it don't have to be based on the response I just wanted to collect the number of YESs or number of NOs they are medical questions they are like a diagnosis questions and the collected answers either the yes or the no will be counted and will be displayed as a percentage that is what I wanted to do and also I will have a counter function to count those answers. I will try your suggestion Mr sidgate thanks and Mr John Oberhauser also thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The following could be an approach to solve this:

```kotlin
val QUESTIONS = listOf(
    "Question 1:Do you have ... ?",
    "Question 2:Do you have ... ?",
    "Question 3:Do you feel ... ?",
    "Question 4:Do you have ... ?",
    "Question 5:Do you have ... ?",
    "Question 6:Do you have ... ?",
    "Question 7:Do you have ... ?",
    "Question 8:Do you feel ... ?",
    "Question 9:Do you have redness or flaky skin ... ?",
    "Question 10:Do you feel pain in any area of ... ?",
)

var yesCount = 0
var noCount = 0

fun main() {
    QUESTIONS.forEach {
        askQuestionAndParseResponse(it)
    }

    println("Result -> Yes - ${yesCount.toPercentage()}%, No - ${noCount.toPercentage()}%")
}

private fun askQuestionAndParseResponse(question: String) {
    println(question)
    val response = readln()
    when (response.trim().lowercase()) {
        "yes" -> yesCount++
        "no" -> noCount++
        else -> {
            println("Sorry! The answer can only be \"yes\" or \"no\"")
            askQuestionAndParseResponse(question)
        }
    }
}

private fun Int.toPercentage(): String =
    "%.2f".format((this.toDouble() / QUESTIONS.size) * 100)
```